# Rails, same piece of code won't work with 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I have this on the erb:

```
<%= fields_for camera, :index =>camera.id do |field|%>
<%= field.check_box :alertflag %>
```

And this on the controller:

```
 @camera = Camera.update(params[:camera].keys, params[:camera].values)
```

And it works on one server which have Rails 3.0.9, but for some reason it doesn't work the same way on one server which have Rails 3.2.

The params hash is like this on 3.0.9:

```
camera%5B10%5D%5Balertflag%5D=0
```

On 3.2:

```
camera%5Balertflag%5D=0
```

So the index is missing.

Comment: In what way does it no longer work? What does the submitted params hash look like?

Comment: @FrederickCheung I added the information to the question. So basically the index is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index` option is supported in both Rails versions. But when comparing the source code of the `FormHelper` module in the two Rails versions it becomes clear that the `fields_for` method signature has changed from:

```
def fields_for(record_or_name_or_array, *args, &block)
```

in [Rails 3.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1143), to

```
def fields_for(record_name, record_object = nil, fields_options = {}, &block)
```

in [Rails 3.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1292).

So if you need to pass the `options` (e.g. the `index`), you must pass it as **the 3rd argument** to the method now, so something like the following should work:

```
<%= fields_for :camera, camera, :index => camera.id do |field| %>
```